# Change an image based on JQuery UI Slider position

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an image on a web page, and want to change it based on the position of a slider, I have looked through a few answers on here but nothing quite covers it for the way I need it to work.

So far i have a functioning slider, and an image but i cant get them to talk to each other:

HTML:

```
<img src="images/flask_image1.png" alt="Isa lab" id="flask" />
```

Slider HTML:

```
<div id="slider1">
```

Script:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#slider1" ).slider({
    min: 0,
    max: 4,
    step: 1,
    change: function(event, ui){
        if(ui.value == 1){
            $('flask').attr('src','images/flask_image2.png');
        }else{
            $('flask').attr('src','images/flask_image1.png');
        };
    }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Basically does nothing.

I'm not a JS or JQ user much, so i'm stuck!

Comment: Just have to say I love out everybody is cluelessly answering your question with the same answer as the previous answerer.

Comment: I know! well thats SE for you!
Mind you, I've started to write an answer before on a question with no answers and 2 other people posted the same answer at the same time...

Comment: Dw, it happens to me often as well. I just delete or edit my post if it does.

Comment: I've start writing an answer and the OP deletes the question!  That's *annoying*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `$('flask')` to `$('#flask')`

Answer (score 0):

`$('flask').attr('src','images/flask_image2.png');`

You need to add a `#` before hand to refer to an element with an ID of flask

```
if(ui.value == 1){
    $('#flask').attr('src','images/flask_image2.png');
}else{
    $('#flask').attr('src','images/flask_image1.png');
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change  `$('flask')` to  `$('#flask')`

Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/4WEML/1/

Comment: @MilindAnantwar I was not aware of above answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you mention id with out the hash "#"
Like below

```
 $('flask').attr('src','images/flask_image2.png');
```

**this wont work** as because thats a **id  you should use hash '#'** so try like below code

```
$(function() {
    $( "#slider1" ).slider({
    min: 0,
    max: 4,
    step: 1,
    change: function(event, ui){
        if(ui.value == 1){
           $('#flask').attr('src','images/flask_image2.png');
        }else{
            $('#flask').attr('src','images/flask_image1.png');
        };
    }
    });
  });
```

Hope this helps....